Azure Functions isolated logging
I am currently writing an Azure Function and had a look into the documentation of Azure Function.
This documentation suggest to remove the default rule for application insights: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#managing-log-levels

The rest of your application continues to work with ILogger and ILogger. However, by default, the Application Insights SDK adds a logging filter that instructs the logger to capture only warnings and more severe logs. If you want to disable this behavior, remove the filter rule as part of service configuration

LoggerFilterRule defaultRule = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");
if (defaultRule is not null)
{
   options.Rules.Remove(defaultRule);
}

However this documentation suggest doing it via the host.json https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#ilogger-logs

It's important to note that the following example doesn't cause the Application Insights provider to capture Information logs. It doesn't capture it because the SDK adds a default logging filter that instructs ApplicationInsights to capture only Warning logs and more severe logs. Application Insights requires an explicit override.

{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
       "logLevel": {
          "Default": "Information"
    }
  }
}

But this seems to have absolute no effect on the default filter rule added when I debug and check which rules are loaded. Even after the updates in the host.json it seems this filter rule is still set to warnings.

So the question is really, is there any way to control that behavior over the host.json/configuration at all?

What is your requirement?

I am bit confused right now, what I actually need to do, to configure the worker level log level to include information level logging

Are you comfortable to get it done without using LoggerFilterRule?

You can do it by using ILogger like this

I am aware how to log. It is more in the setup. Looking at the docs we have this comment:
The rest of your application continues to work with ILogger and ILogger. However, by default, the Application Insights SDK adds a logging filter that instructs the logger to capture only warnings and more severe logs. If you want to disable this behavior, remove the filter rule as part of service configuration

Yes, It will be applicable if you are using application insight Sdk

Yes, but the second documentation is telling that is overridable also via the host.json - but if I do it, it seems to have no effect when I debug. The default rule seems to still in place with warning as log level. So I am not sure whether the log level via the host.json has any effect or if the first documentation is the only way.

If you only add the log level in host.json file then it will work see this. It is mentioned that Application Insights requires an explicit override but not that the host.json file will override. If you are not intent to use application insight sdk then you can only go for host.json file logging

We are using application insights. That is the whole point of this filter rule, my question is - if there is another way than removing that default rule. The host.json seems to have no effect as the filter rule is still in place if I look at it in the debugger.

You still can use application insight without using the filter rules

Why to use the filter rule if you want to override it?

The filter rule is added by default. I am looking for a way how to configure this one. And the second documentation suggested that over the host.json it is possible. But when I look at the filter rules after the function was initialized it seems that is still the default one. So, you are saying that the filter rule does not apply if the host.json is set?

Refer this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78673187/application-insights-logging-configuration-ignored-on-azure-functions-v4-net-8#:~:text=Adding%20AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__logLevel__function%20has%20no%20effect,%20nor%20%E2%80%A6

You can add the default log level using host.json file and making the below changes in program.cs file.
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
      "logLevel": {
        "Function.Function1": "Information"
      }
    }
}

using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
        {
            LoggerFilterRule defaultRule = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");

            if (defaultRule is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(defaultRule);
            }
        });
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
    {
        config.AddJsonFile("host.json", optional: true);
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
    {
        logging.AddApplicationInsights(console =>
        {
            console.IncludeScopes = true;
        });

        logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

I am using default .Net8 isolated function code as given below.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace _79026563
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
        }
    }
}

I am getting all the information logs as given below and it does work.

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.6280 Commit hash: N/A +421f0144b42047aa289ce691dc6db4fc8b6143e6 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875

[2024-09-26T12:36:15.636Z] Found C:\Users\*****\79026563\79026563.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2024-09-26T12:36:18.749Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 38560) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2024-09-26T12:36:18.794Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        Function1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7025/api/Function1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-09-26T12:36:23.854Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000000D2022A4'.
[2024-09-26T12:36:37.667Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=9e791713-f046-4d2c-adc1-8f6130e3ad21)
[2024-09-26T12:36:38.052Z] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-09-26T12:36:38.058Z] Executing OkObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.String'.
[2024-09-26T12:36:38.147Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=9e791713-f046-4d2c-adc1-8f6130e3ad21, Duration=542ms)


can you open options.Rules in your debugger please. What loglevel is set there?
Cause if I do not run options.Rules.Remove(defaultRule); and just add the loglevel override nothing happens.

@JulianHüppauff That was incorrect screenshot, added the correct one

But shouldn't there be there a filter rule, how otherwise would you filter out trace level logs for example? Or is the loglevel applied after the filterRule? Or e.g. you want just error level logs

Yeah log level is applied after the filter rule. You need to set the default log level as per the higher severity
